# else condition after an if (multiple conditions) (C)

Tags: c

I'm writing some lines of code in C.

what I would like to know is: if I have the following condition:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    do something
} else if (condition1) {
    do something else
}
```

Would this be correct? or does the else only admits conditions that exclude the ones specified inside the if?

I guess this would not make sense in case of logical OR (||) instead of &&, cause in that case it would mean that if we reach the else, BOTH condition1 and condition2 would be false. But with &&, I assume it would be correct since the first condition inside the if is given by the matching of BOTH conditions, so the else might be just one of them (so meaning condition2 is false).

is this  correct?
`

Haven't tried this on actual code yet, was just trying to solve this theoretically before moving to the code.

Comment: *"Haven't tried this on actual code yet"* - You are encouraged to.  When you test your code, which operation produces an unexpected result?

Comment: You can put any condition you want there. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. The language has no built-in restrictions on how the conditions related in `if` and `else if`. Some relationships may not be useful -- your point about `||` is correct.

However, it may be clearer to refactor using nested `if` so you don't repeat conditions. This is also more efficient if calculating the conditions is expensive.

```
if (condition1) {
    if (condition2) {
        do something
    } else {
        do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be correct? or does the else only admits conditions that exclude the ones specified inside the if?

An `else` block is executed if and only if control reaches the associated `if` statement, and the condition of the `if` evaluates to a falsey value.

But that doesn't make your example inherently wrong.  Your `if` condition is
`condition1 && condition2`, which can evaluate to a falsey value despite `condition1` being truthy.

> I guess this would not make sense in case of logical OR (||) instead of &&, cause in that case it would mean that if we reach the else, BOTH condition1 and condition2 would be false.

Yes, if the `if` condition were `condition1 || condition2` then the `if` branch would be taken whenever `condition1` was true (and sometimes when it wasn't), so the `else if (condition1)` would be useless, and presumably not what was intended (but not strictly speaking *wrong* as far as the language goes).

Answer (score 0):

`if` either goes in that branch, or it doesn't. If the first conditions matched, the first branch ran.

You can work through this by exploring various permutations of values:

| condition1 | condition2 | branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | 1st |
| true | false | 2nd |
| false | true | none |
| false | false | none |